# Python ANSI Colour codes transparent background

Tags: python, colors, ansi-colors

I was wondering if it was possible to set the background colour of text, using ANSI colour codes, to transparent, or just the colour of the terminal, so you can use colours without having to deal with the background colour not being the right colour.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by ending the escape code using `49m`. For example, red text on a transparent background would be `\033[1;31;49m`.

Happy colouring!